# Pass data with url in angular2 causes error

Tags: http, angular

```
this.params={
  "id": this.id,
  "fields": "language,largeIcon,shortDescription,subtitleLanguagesCsv,video,videoId,aboutTheCourse,faq,courseSyllabus,courseFormat,suggestedReadings,instructor,estimatedClassWorkload,recommendedBackground,sessions.fields(durationString),instructors.fields(photo150,fullName,title,department,middleName),universities.fields(name,locationCity,logo,squareLogo),categories.fields(id,name)",
  "includes": "universities,categories,instructors,sessions"
};

 this.courseraService.view("courses",this.params)
     .subscribe (response => {
         this.courseDetails = response.elements[0];
      }, error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);



view(model,data) {

    this.url = this.courseraUrl + model;

    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        for (let key in data) {
                  params.set(key, data[key]);
        }
    let options = new RequestOptions({search: params});

    return this.http.get(this.url ,options)
        .map ( response => response.json())
        // .do( data => console.log ('view: ' + JSON.stringify(data) ) )
                  .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This shows an error in the data which try to pass with url. The error is:

`Cannot read property 'photo150' of undefined`

Comment: format your code once!

Comment: have you try to print params in view function. doing that you come to know that you are setting correct params or not.